# Heroku Web Server Won't Start Locally

Tags: python, heroku

I am having problems starting heroku web server localy. Here is the error message I am constantlly getting:

```
PS C:\Users\Dragan\heroku_workspace\python-getting-started> heroku local
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
10:01:32 web.1   |  Traceback (most recent call last):
10:01:32 web.1   |    File "c:\users\dragan\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
10:01:32 web.1   |      "__main__", mod_spec)
10:01:32 web.1   |    File "c:\users\usr1\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
10:01:32 web.1   |      exec(code, run_globals)
10:01:32 web.1   |    File 
C:\Users\Dragan\Anaconda3\Scripts\gunicorn.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
10:01:32 web.1   |    File "c:\users\dragan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\app\wsgiapp.py", line 10, in <module>
10:01:32 web.1   |      from gunicorn.app.base import Application
10:01:32 web.1   |    File "c:\users\dragan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\app\base.py", line 12, in <module>
10:01:32 web.1   |      from gunicorn import util
10:01:32 web.1   |    File "c:\users\dragan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gunicorn\util.py", line 9, in <module>
10:01:32 web.1   |      import fcntl
10:01:32 web.1   |  ImportError: No module named 'fcntl'
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
10:01:33 web.1   Exited with exit code 1
```

I am following every step described in this tutorial [LINK](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally)
I installed the virtual environment inside the project 'python-getting-started'. I am trying to start the local web server from the project's root directory.

Can anybody help me resolve this issue?

UPDATE_1: I have installed Heroku Toolbelt for Windows, and I have installed Anaconda for Python.

Comment: Gunicorn does not support Windows. See https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/524 for details.

Comment: @KlausD.is there any fix for the issue? I can't get anything from the infos in the link.

Comment: @KlausD.by the way, I also installed the 'Heroku Toolbelt for Windows' suggested on the heroku website. Thus, I suppose those components should be included in the toolbelt. Right?

Answer (score 20):

According to the Heroku tutorial, try this in Windows instead of `heroku local`:

```
heroku local web -f Procfile.windows
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#run-the-app-locally

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to deploy a Python web application to Heroku using the [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) web server. This works great on Heroku, but CANNOT WORK on Windows because gunicorn only runs on *nix based operating systems.

What you can do instead of running `heroku local` is run your web server WITHOUT gunicorn locally. Simply say something like `$ python myapp.py` or whatever your main python web server file is. That will start your server locally using Python ONLY, and not gunicorn.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @vkc is correct but incomplete.

As mentioned by the documentation, we should use `heroku local web -f Procfile.windows` command on windows to run our app locally.

This command simply means run the app locally and use `Procfile.windows` as the Procfile instead of the default one ('Procfile').

So for this to work, we need to create a file called `Procfile.windows` at the root directory of our project and add this line to it;

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
```

Which means run the server at port 5000.

Also before doing that, we need to have environment variables (if any) available locally in a `.env` file.

We can get the list of our env variables by running this command;

```
heroku config
```

copy the result and create a `.env` file and paste the result in it.

Also don't forget to set the variables properly;

```
VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE (no quotes required)
```

Also add this file to `.gitignore`.

After that, run this command;

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

And you are good to go.