# Anaconda does not execture Python command

Tags: python, anaconda

I am having problems with Anaconda when trying to run the follwing command: python manage.py collectstatic

Does anybody know how to resolve the issue and what is the issue at all?

Here is the error message:

```
PS C:\Users\Dragan\heroku_workspace\python-getting-started> python manage.py collectstatic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Dragan\Anaconda3\lib\site-Packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Dragan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Dragan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 195, in fetch_command
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Users\Dragan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
return module.Command()
  File "C:\Users\Dragan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py", line 32, in __init__
self.storage.path('')
  File "C:\Users\Dragan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 204, in inner
self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\Dragan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 394, in _setup
self._wrapped = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)()
  File "C:\Users\Dragan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 328, in get_storage_class
return import_string(import_path or settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE)
  File "C:\Users\Dragan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\Dragan\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in 
all_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'whitenoise'
```

Comment: Is whitenoise installed? If not, please do it by `pip install whitenoise`

Comment: @be_good_do_good It asks me constantly if I want to owervrite existing files when I try to run the command. I always type 'yes' but nothing happens.

Comment: @be_good_do_good I think it even works... however, now I am stucked when I run the command "heroku local"; do you have maybe any advice? here is the output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930678/heroku-web-server-wont-start-locally